# Complimentary Multiply With Carry period

Tags: random, computer-science

I'm trying to figure out what the period of a particular CMWC pseudo-random number generator would be.

The wikipedia page has some examples of the period of different parameters for both a standard MWC and CMWC, but doesn't really answer how this is calculated.

Is there an easy way to calculate this for a given multiplier, r number of seeds, and base b?

For example, say I have the following parameters (for a CMWC):

`b=2^32-1`
`a=4294966362`
`r=32`

I have verified that `p=a*b^r+1` is prime.

edit: oops, copied the wrong a value. Fixed it so p should be prime now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've misunderstood what is required to get a full period:

`b` must also be a primitive root of `p`, which I don't think is the case here (to be honest, I don't have the math background to even begin to understand what a primitive root is). If there is a full period, the period would be `a*b^r`. As far as I can tell, it's impossible (or at least very difficult) to tell what the period would be otherwise (and quite frankly, it's not useful because in practice a full period is desired).

Source: [Journal Of Modern Applied Statistical Methods](http://education.wayne.edu/jmasm/vol2_no1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

b is a primitive root when its order is p-1, so b^k can assume every value from 1 to p-1, depending on value of k.

The order of an element is the minimum s with b^s=1 (mod p).
b is a primitive root if, and only if, b^(phi(p)/k) != 1 (!= means different) for every k divisor of phi(p), and phi(p) = (p-1) is the Euler's totient function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

In your example:
- phi(p) = a*b^r = p - 1.
- Divisors of a are {1, 2, 3, 31, 23091217, 4294966362}.
- Divisors of b are {1, 3, 5, 17, 257, 65537, 4294967295}.

So, (p-1) = 2*(3^33)*(5^32)*(17^32)*31*(257^32)*(65537^32)*23091217.
p-1 has 322,570,512 divisors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)

With modular exponentiation, it is possible to see that
b^((p-1)/3) = 1 (mod p)
so the order of b is different of p-1.

It is better choose numbers *a* and *b* with few divisors, then p-1 also will have few divisors, and it will be easy to calculate (phi(p) / k) for every divisor k. Order of b will be min{phi(p) / k} = min{(p-1)/k}.

In Marsaglia's article "On the randomness of Pi and other decimal expansions" (http://interstat.statjournals.net/YEAR/2005/articles/0510005.pdf), there are some values of a, b and r. Periods that are not full ate usefull too (see article).

Base b=2^32 doesn't have full period, but it returns integers from 0 to 2^32-1. Base b=2^32-1 can't return unbiased 32 bit integers (it will never return number 2^31-1 = 4294967295).

Comment: +1 puts the math all in one place. I had to go searching around for hours to put all this together.